# Is Emoticon recognized as a script by `fontspec`?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ucharclasses

I am using `xelatex` to typeset different scripts that belong to disjoint Unicode blocks using the MWE file below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[Latin,Tamil,Greek]{ucharclasses}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}
\newfontfamily\tamilfont[Script=Tamil]{Noto Sans Tamil}
\setTransitionsFor{Tamil}{\tamilfont}{\normalfont}
\newfontfamily\emojifont{Symbola}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
%
\begin{document}
Omnia vincit amor. வாய்மையே வெல்லும். Ελευθερία ή θάνατος. \emojifont⌚️⏲️☘️\normalfont. 
\end{document}
```

The MWE gives the desired output when run through `xelatex`.

But, because Emoticons are not recognized as a script in `fontspec`, it is not possible to invoke the emoticons without the two font changes shown in the MWE.

Otherwise, one could say

```
\newfontfamily\emojifont[Script=Emoticon]{Symbola}
\setTransitionsFor{Emoticon}{\emojifont}{\normalfont}
```

and invoke the emoticons without explicitly specifying the fonts. But, as things stand, this does not work.

My question is whether there is an elegant workaround at present, and if not, whether, as a feature request, Emoticons could be considered as a `Script` in `fontspec` in future.

Comment: the script of font and the names of ucharclasses are different things. The first is a font feature, the second describes an unicodeblock. Your watch (U+231A) is in `MiscellaneousTechnical`, so you should be able to setup a transition with this. (I don't have your fonts, so can't test it.

Comment: There is also a `symbols` informal super-block in `ucharclasses`.

Comment: Note that, in LuaLaTeX, you could load Babel and enable `\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{tamil}` to switch the language and font to Tamil whenever it sees the Tamil script. It’s also possible to set the individual emoji active with `newunicodchar`, e.g. `\newunicodechar{^^^^231a}{{\emojifont\symbol"231A}}`.